# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo csv desde internet con python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

quisiera descargar un archivo csv desde un sitio en internet, pero
no puedo lograrlo, ya que me encuentro con este error

**Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)**

y no se como abrir el archivo en modo texto estoy usando python 3 y las librerias urllib, csv.

```
import csv
import urllib

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv'
respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
archivo = csv.reader(response)
for filas in archivo:
    print(filas)
```

Comment: ¿Que es `response`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que retorna urlopen es un objeto HTTPResponse, este tiene un metodo data que retorna los bytes, estos bytes lo convertimos a string con bytearray().decode(), pero csv.reader() no acepta string como entrada para ello usamos StringIO.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from io import StringIO

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv'
respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
f = StringIO(bytearray(respuesta.read()).decode())
archivo = csv.reader(f)
for filas in archivo:
    print(filas)
```